# Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: запятая

Разгорелся спор: нужна ли запятая после слова "узнаете" в предложении "В этот раз название фильма вы узнаете только когда придете на просмотр".
Буду благодарен, если подскажете, какое тут действует (или не действует :)) правило. Спасибо!

Comment: @Gene Gorz, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Правилам, конечно же, нужно следовать, но в данном случае это печальная необходимось. Ради соблюдения обобщающей условности приходится ставить запятую там, где нет речевой паузы (в противоречии с интонацией).
Это может помешать с первого раза правильно прочитать фразу вслух (напр. диктору) или уловить акцент фразы (напр. в субтитре к фильму). Если при чтении в месте запятой сделать паузу, то меняется оттенок смысла:
"название фильма вы узнаете, (но) только когда придете на просмотр".
При таком прочтении часть фразы до запятой подтверждает, что адресат узнает-таки название (будто он в самой возможности этого сомневался), и добавляется лёгкая оговорка, что это произойдёт не сразу (подразумеваемое "но"). Однако, для этой фразы акцент нужен не на подтверждении того, что название фильма станет известно (хоть и с оговорками), а на том самом ограничении (рано вам это знать), которое сообщают напр. человеку, спросившему о названии. Поэтому она должна звучать без пауз - как фраза "название фильма вы узнаете только перед самым просмотром". В примере же, иллюстрирующем правило (о весне) ничего подобного нет: там запятая не противоречит паузе перед уточняющим оборотом с "особенно". 
Так что, будь моя воля, для защиты от ложных "препинаний" я ввёл бы правило отбрасывания предварительно расставленных запятых там, где они противоречат интонации - хотя бы для текстов, предназначенных специально для прочтения аудитории вслух.

Answer (score 0):

§ 116. Если перед простым подчинительным союзом стоят усилительно-ограничительные слова (частицы, союзы или их сочетания, вводные слова) особенно, даже, в частности, в том числе, 
в особенности, а именно, а также, а (но) только, как раз, лишь, исключительно, **только** и др., то **запятая ставится перед ними**, а не перед союзом: Неповторим Ярославль, ни с каким городом не спутаешь его, особенно когда увидишь город с Волги (М. Рапов); Хорошо в лесу весной, особенно когда (если) почки на деревьях только-только начинают раскрываться; Она обещала приехать, но только когда закончатся экзамены.[Здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=616)

***...узнаете, только когда...***

Comment: спасибо. тоже склонялся к этой версии. уточнение,             чтобы избежать всех неясностей:                                                                                                           сочинительную ли функцию выполняет здесь союз "когда" -"узнаете" и "придете" выглядят как однородные члены? 

Comment: Понятны ваши сомнения, но перед нами сложноподчинённое предложение с союзом когда, присоединяющим придаточное. Да, оба предложения односоставные определённо-личные, но всё-таки одно из них главное (от него можно задать вопрос КОГДА?), а другое придаточное. Союз КОГДА подчинительный.

Answer (score 0):

Правилам, конечно же, нужно следовать, но в данном случае это печальная необходимось. Ради соблюдения обобщающей условности приходится ставить запятую там, где нет речевой паузы (в противоречии с интонацией).
Это может помешать с первого раза правильно прочитать фразу вслух (напр. диктору) или уловить акцент фразы (напр. в субтитре к фильму). Если при чтении в месте запятой сделать паузу, то меняется оттенок смысла:
"название фильма вы узнаете, (но) только когда придете на просмотр".
При таком прочтении часть фразы до запятой подтверждает, что адресат узнает-таки название (будто он в самой возможности этого сомневался), и добавляется лёгкая оговорка, что это произойдёт не сразу (подразумеваемое "но"). Однако, для этой фразы акцент нужен не на подтверждении того, что название фильма станет известно (хоть и с оговорками), а на том самом ограничении (рано вам это знать), которое сообщают напр. человеку, спросившему о названии. Поэтому она должна звучать без пауз - как фраза "название фильма вы узнаете только перед самым просмотром". В примере же, иллюстрирующем правило (о весне) ничего подобного нет: там запятая не противоречит паузе перед уточняющим оборотом с "особенно". 
Так что, будь моя воля, для защиты от ложных "препинаний" я ввёл бы правило отбрасывания предварительно расставленных запятых там, где они противоречат интонации - хотя бы для текстов, предназначенных специально для прочтения аудитории вслух.